# pytorch: index out of bound for index bigger than batch size

Tags: mnist, index-error, batchsize

I am trying to predict some images from MNIST using Pytorch, and I cannot choose whatever index from 0-60,000.
First I added "drop_last=True" because I noticed the last incomplete batch was not discarded, and I thought that would solve the problem, but it didn't. If I have a batch size of 256, the max index I can choose to predict is 255. How should I solve this? 
Here is how I get my images:

```
images = MNIST('mnist_data',transform=T, download=True, train=True)
image_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(images,batch_size=256, drop_last=True, shuffle=True)
```

and how i try to make a prediction:

```
image_index = 258
value = (images[image_index])
prediction = Net().forward(value)
```

Then I get 
IndexError: index 258 is out of bounds for dimension 0 with size 256

Answer (score 0):

It's principally because you are trying to index to a value greater than the length of your array/tensor. You would want to increase batch size to fix it